# Is there a new font?

Tags: discussion, font

I've noticed the site looks really different. Is this a new font, or am I crazy?

It looks really nice, IMO.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

I'm using Chrome on OSX.

Comment: I haven't noticed anything, but I know that the site is undergoing minor UI changes at Canonical's request. Have you perhaps changed browsers or maybe you're using Windows at the moment? It looks slightly different in each circumstance. You might have also specified a custom font in your browser's CSS files...

Comment: @Seth Of course I'm using Windows. It's the new cool OS. </sarcasm> Here's what I'm seeing: http://d.pr/i/ZmfP

Comment: Hmm. That's not what I see. Later I can check it against Windows and Opera. Didn't fit either Chromium or Firefox on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Ohh, that looks like the Ubuntu font.

Comment: @Seth I'm on Chrome on OS X.

Comment: @IanCarroll That's very important! ;)

Comment: @seth :P I didn't think there would be much variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YEAY Ubuntu Font!

[image]

---

Testing on Kubuntu, firefox (I do have ubuntu font installed on system if that is a factor), (non working on rkonq);  Working on Mac, firefox and Opera

---

So, here is how it is looking without the Ubuntu font:
[image]

Notice the "u" and "n"

Comment: OH! OH! OH! I have the Ubuntu font installed on this computer! OH! :P

Comment: Ah, that might be it then, It didn't work on my Android tablet.

Comment: I don't like it.